# django python def choices/documentation

Tags: jquery, django

In Django Python, where can I find documentation about all available def? For example, I have

```
def clean(self):
```

and

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

I want to know what my possible options are for def. For example, I want to force a decimal field to return a string. Which def can I override that would allow me to cast a return value?

Is there some documentation out there that someone could point me to on this subject?

Comment: Before Starting django,first learn python !

Comment: Try the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/) and [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/).

Comment: @MohitHarshan that didn’t help

Comment: If you had any basic idea about python or django ,you wouldn't post this question here.

Comment: You guys are acting like i didn’t already do all kinds of web searches about it before i posted a question on here. I posted the question for assistance, not for unhelpful comments

Comment: @MohitHarshan i have the basics. Ok, let me put it this way: if i search for python def in a web search, i get all kinds of results about basics. However, i understand the basic concepts. What i AM looking for is the built-in def functions that i can override. Hey man, if i see that you didn’t know some things about getting girls, i would try to help point you in the proper direction instead of saying hey, go learn about girls

Comment: For a start, there isn't a thing called a "def", these are functions or methods - calling them the right thing will probably help your googling. But you are not asking a question that can be answered. Override where? Models, views, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For class based views, there's a very handy site which outlines all the included methods:

https://ccbv.co.uk

I keep it handy at all times. Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for your useful input, and I'm going to look all through this right now.